# Spring Data REST links and Ribbon Client loadbalancer

Tags: load-balancing, spring-data-rest, spring-cloud, hateoas, netflix-eureka

We use two Microservices (apple and banana), one Registry Server (registry) and one GUI-Client(client).

The Microservices expose their resources with Spring Data Rest, so a link for a single resource in the HAL Resource representing the list of apples might look like this:

```
"link_": "http://localhost:8080/apples/123", or "http://192.168.0.23/..."
```

, depending on how i access the list.

The restTemplate in the GUI (backed up by ribbon) can manage the first call on receiving the list, because i manually use the adress

```
http://apple/apples
```

Ribbon will now look up the **apple** client id and change the request address to "http://localhost:8080/apples".

But now  i can't traverse the retrieved links, because they will no more point to the client id and won't get any loadbalancing. Also if this peticular instance will die, the url in the link won't be valid, even if other instances are still running.

**Is there a way to change the host that Spring Data REST puts into the links to a fixed value?**

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. In [our sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/customers-stores/tree/master/rest-microservices-customers/src/main/java/example/customers/integration) that uses Spring Data Rest, we have the same issue. This [PR](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/customers-stores/tree/master/rest-microservices-customers/src/main/java/example/customers/integration) was just merged that might help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped the RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory of Spencer Gibb to trick Spring Data REST. I won't recommend this solution, its only temporary.

```
template.setRequestFactory((uri, httpMethod) -> {
    final ClientHttpRequest request = ribbonClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(uri, httpMethod);
    if (!uri.equals(request.getURI()))
        request.getHeaders().add("X-Forwarded-Host",uri.getHost());
    return request;
});
```